# Location of libtensorflow.so and headers after building tensorflow r1.12 with bazel on Linux

Tags: linux, tensorflow, bazel

after having a lot of troubles building earlier versions of tensorflow using cmake I decided to give bazel a go since it supposedly is able to create a shared library. As per official recommendation I downloaded and built bazel 0.15 and then used

```
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

in the hopes of being able to build a shared library. After almost two hours bazel claimed that it was able to build libtensorflow.so, however, I cannot find it anywhere. It is especially strange since the whole directory is only about 650MB large. Earlier I built tensorflow r1.10 using cmake which generated a libtensorflow.so (which does not work in my test project due to other reasons) and that alone was over 800 MB large; the whole cmake directory was over 11GB in size.

Furthermore my test project (that actually works under Windows with an earlier version of tensorflow) requires some headers like

```
tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h
```

but it seems that this file hasn't been generated either because I cannot find it.

Can someone please tell me the correct way of getting a shared library and the necessary headers or where I find them after the supposed successful bazel build.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I now find out that the command find doesn't look in symlinks and so I was able to find libtensorflow.so (albeit a much smaller one with a size of about 100MB) and some headers in one of the symlinked directories that are created by bazel in your working path, i.e. bazel-bin, bazel-out etc.

Howevere, I am now stuck with another problem. As I mentioned above there were some headers but not all. For instance I cannot find

```
google/protobuf/stubs/common.h
```

Does anyone know how I can get all the rest of the headers like the one mentioned above, Eigen, Tensor and what not. What bazel target do I need to specify or how do I get them otherwise?